# Comparing dates, and storing in data frame. Then adding another dimension to events with same date time, to denote number of simultaneous events

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvqjW.png)I have a huge data table with date-time columns being one of them. I have to create data frame for each date. Within each data frame, I have to compare which have the same time too, and add another variable to denote the simultaneous events. The first date would be "1/1/2016 0:00". Suppose there are 2 events with exact same date-time, then it should change to"1/1/2016 0:00:2"in the data frame.

I want to compare each row and count the number of simlutanoues events and store them in a data frame. Have been trying to use this code, but doesnt work.

```
for(j in 1:1000){
  c=0
 for(k in 2:1000){
   if(td4[j,1]==td4[k,1]){#compare rows
    c=c+1    #count the number of rows
  }
 }
 d[p]<-td4[k,1]  #store a particular element
  e[p]<-c           #store the corresponding number of simultanoues events
```

}

```
td5<-cbind.data.frame(d,e)   #combine them together in a data frame
```

Comment: Given n rows with the same datetime t, would you expect each row's datetime to increase by 0 to n-1?

Comment: I would like to add another parameter after the datetime to represent the number of events happening at the same time. So it may read-
1/1/2016 0:00:1,1/1/2016 0:00:2....

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#for changing values to next second
for(i in 2:nrow(a)){
  if(a$datetime[i]==a$datetime[i-1])
    a$datetime[i]<-a$datetime[i-1]+1
  else
    a$datetime[i]<-a$datetime[i]
}


#for splitting data date wise
a$date<-as.Date(a$datetime)

aa<-split(a,a$date)
```

## updated

I am not sure if I understand the exact thing you are looking for, but if you just want to count the number of rows in each second, then try this

```
library(plyr)
c<-as.data.frame(table(df$t4)) #gives count for each second
names(c)<-c("t4","Freq")

df<-merge(df,c,by="t4",all.x=T)
```

If this is not what you want, then I suggest upload a data frame of input example and a example of what u exactly need

Comment: @NikhilSanjayPawar Can u share an example of data that you are working on?

Comment: I have added the image. td4 is the time in seconds, starting from 0 to 3600*24. I want to compare count the number of simultanoues events at each second(0,1,2.....3600*24) and add a dummy number at the end of each second to represent the number of simultanoues events.